# How to setup Amazon S3 policy for ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

I am using an S3-compatible storage (digital ocean spaces) to host images from my web application.
To prevent hotlinking and minimize direct downloads I applied this policy:

```
{
   "Id": ip referer policy example",
   "Statement": [
    {
       "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from my server.",
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:GetObject",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
       "Condition": {
         "NotIpAddress":  {
          "aws:SourceIp":  "server-ip-address"
        }
      }
    } 
  ]
}
```

The trick seemed to work and I am now unable to access the files directly, however, neither can my web application. Have I done something wrong?

Is there a way to debug a referrer or something?

Comment: Is the content being retrieved for use by the web app itself, or are you providing a link/reference in HTML pages?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the web app has API access and fetches the unsigned URL (it does work before I apply the policy)

Comment: What do you mean by "the unsigned URL"? Does it make API calls to Digital Ocean Spaces, or does it make HTTP/S calls to the public URL of the bucket?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant "signed url". Temporary URL that gets generated by the API to view private files.
I think I now see where my misconception comes from... I am making calls to the URL generated by the bucket API (temporary URL). I am not actually making calls to `GetObject` (which should download the file contents, right?)

Comment: If the pre-signed URL is being used by "end users" to view the files in their browser, then the request will come from their browser and their IP address rather than the server. The policy is blocking such access.

Comment: The request that generates the URLs comes from the app. Not sure if that should make difference

Comment: Where are those URLs being used -- on the server, or in user's web browsers?

Comment: In the browser... e.g. `<img src="url"/>`

Comment: Then that's your answer... The user's browser will be sending the pre-signed URL to Digital Ocean. Their IP address will _not_ match your Server IP address, so the request will be denied. It doesn't matter where the URL was constructed -- what matters is from where the request is being made to Digital Ocean.

Comment: Okay, that explains it. However, I am not sure why it fails for my local machine IP address. And is there no workaround for this issue?

Comment: It all depends on your goal. You said you want to "prevent hotlinking and minimize direct downloads". Pre-signed URLs are only valid for a limited time, which should meet those goals. You can shorten the duration to a minute (or even less!), since the URL should be generated while the HTML is being generated, and the user's browser will use the link immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I think I came up with a workaround

Comment: @denis Can you share what that was?

Answer (score 0):

Content is private by default. Your policy is not granting any access via an `Allow` statement, so the content is not accessible. The `Deny` can be used to remove permissions granted by an `Allow`, but does not itself grant access.

You could change it into an `Allow` policy, and change `NotIpAddress` into `IpAddress`. This would grant access to your server to download content. However, it would be better to use an S3-style API call to download content from your own bucket rather than using an anonymous HTTP request.

If you are putting a link to the object in an HTML page, then the policy will provide the security that you expect because the user's browser will attempt to access the object and it will be denied access since the request is not originating from your server's IP address.

Comment: Yes, the content is private and its fetching the unsigned URL. Before I apply the policy everything works (the web app has access to S3 API). As soon as I apply the policy - the images stop being accessed, despite URLs fetched from the API.

Comment: If you are saying that the application makes API requests (eg `get_object()`) and it was working until this policy was added, then it suggests that the app is using a set of credentials that has already been given `Allow` permissions to access the bucket. The fact that it is now denied suggests that the server is _not_ coming in via the IP address indicated. Are you providing a Public IP address or a Private IP address? Is the server in a public subnet, or a private subnet?

Comment: So yeah, I replaced the IP string with my local IP address and now I still can't access the public URL directly. So clearly something isn't right. Speaking of the server, I am providing its public IP address